# apiary service responding 410 Gone

Tags: apiary.io

I am using apiary service to generate the offline documentation using below command

apiary preview --path=docs/tmpApi.apib

It was working so far, but noticed today that it is giving error "apiary service responded with an error: 410 Gone".

Any idea, what has gone wrong with the service?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the apiaryio gem please. I was able to make it work on my side.
It sounds like the older gem is pointing to an old version of the service - we'll improve that error message.

Emmanuel

Comment: Thanks for the response. After update service works fine. But is seems that the newer version generates the documentation is different format. May be I need to check the changes/features in the 0.3.2 version.